# Handling concurrent attempts on a SQL transaction (special situation)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I have 3 tables in a SQL Server 2008R2 database, that I need to fill their records right after each other so I used transaction to do this job with no problem. basically I have 2 INSERT store procedure queries in middle of a transaction to insert records in these tables as the code below;

> The transaction was handled in C# SqlTransaction class at ASP.NET.
>   The following procedures just used in middle of the transaction.

First Table:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [INSERT_RESOURCE]
  @docID int,
  @resTitle nvarchar(500),
  @resCategory nvarchar(100),
  @resType nvarchar(50),
  @resLink nvarchar(MAX),
  @createdBy nvarchar(50),
  @createdDateTime datetime
AS 
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO Resource
   VALUES(@resTitle, @resCategory, @resType, 
          @resLink, @createdBy, @createdDateTime)
END
```

Second Table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [INSERT_RESOURCE_DOCUMENT]
  @docName nvarchar(200),
  @docSize nvarchar(50),
  @docType nvarchar(50),
  @docPath nvarchar(MAX),
  @docTitle nvarchar(100),
  @uploadBy nvarchar(50),
  @uploadDateTime datetime
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Document
        VALUES(@docName, @docSize, @docType, @docPath, 
                           @docTitle, @uploadBy, @uploadDateTime)

INSERT INTO Resource_Document         --Third table
    VALUES(
           (SELECT TOP 1 ResourceID FROM Resource  ORDER BY ResourceID DESC), 
           (SELECT TOP 1 DocID FROM Document  ORDER BY DocID DESC)
          )
```

The above procedures are work fine but the possible issue could be on the third procedure, that is using the last ID of the first two tables to insert data in the third table, but because of the last INSERT statement is using the SELECT TOP 1 query it might pick up the wrong id if **at the same time** someone else use the same transaction to add some values into the first two tables. 
so I was wondering how can I resolve the issue in this transaction ?

is there any other ways that I can used in third store-procedure to get those ids from the first two tables ?

Comment: You say "at the same time someone else use the same transaction". This is your issue. You either need to lock in your code so this can't happen, or use different transactions for each user.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more that how to lock the transaction ? and what do you mean by using different transactions for each user ?

Comment: A Transaction mean each unit of work is committed all/nothing so your database is always in consistent state (either in case of errors or in the case of a multi user environment). Typically, each user request uses a separate transaction. David's answer will fix your particular problem here, but from the way you wrote your question it sounds like you might need to revisit your transaction design for a multi user environment.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is scope. You want to gain the last inserted value for that user, during that transaction. Your select top 1 queries break the scope of the user and may select the last inserted value for **any** user.

To remain in the user scope, take advantage of SQL's scoping methods. Convert all 3 of these actions into one single stored procedure, then use the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` method to get the value that was last inserted into an identity column for this session/user. This will safely guarantee that users won't get each others' inserted values.

**Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx**

Comment: Do not use @@Identity, it isn't limited to a specific scope.

Comment: The OP's question states that multiple people can use the same `SqlTransaction`. How does this approach get rid of the race condition? It looks like it just makes it less likely but still possible.

Comment: It's not that multiple people can use the same SqlTransaction, it is that each person creates a transaction before doing these operations. Transactions are meant for "rolling back" if a part of a complex operation fails... For example if you insert data into 3 tables in a transaction and the second insert throws an error, you can roll back and it will undo all of your changes... Without a transaction you'd have inconsistent state (AKA table 1 has data but 2 and 3 do not when you really wanted either all 3 to have data or none to have data). The transaction is not shared across users.

Comment: @DavidH. The OP says "_if **at the same time** someone else use the same transaction_" (sic). All I'm asking is if you can make clear the definition of scope to the OP in your answer, and how `SCOPE_IDENTITY` works with that so the OP can understand why this approach would work.

Answer (score 0):

The third script will definitely lead to an issue when two records are added at the same time.

I think you could place an after trigger (for every insert on **Resource**) and an after update trigger (for every insert on **Document**).
or you could join the above two tables (**Resource** & **Document**) and then create a trigger which adds the data to the third table (**Resource_Document**)

For reference - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx